# Find the sum of the series $4\sum_{n=-13}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I m stuck on finding the of the series

$$4\sum_{n=-13}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n.$$

Comment: This a sum of geometric sequence. So you have to apply the result in your course:

Comment: We want $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $r$ is the ratio of successive terms while $a$ is the first term. Can you deduce the vales of $a$ and $r$ and hence of $\frac{a}{1-r}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as
$$
4\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m-13}=
4\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-13}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$...=\sum_{n=-13}^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{13}(-3)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

This a sum of geometric sequence. So you have to apply the result in your course: $\sum_{k=0}^n aq^k = a\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1} $ two times.